# Xamarin - Strange icon on file

Tags: xamarin

Hi I'm very new to Xamarin world. I'm seeing a different icon on my ViewModel File & similar icon on related View while other files have different icon.
Any Clue what that icon is signifying.
[image]

My project is correctly building.

thanks
Brijesh Mathur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That icon means the file has changes that need to be committed to version/source control. It will have a blue plus sign if it's a new file that needs to be committed.